# Add index name to a dataframe / serie

Tags: python, pandas

I didn't know how I have to do for the following !
Has someone the solution ?

I have the following dataframe with TEST, DATE and PRODUCTS as indexes. I want to add a PRODUCTS as follow for all TEST and DATE. For example, T3 = T2 + 1

```
>>> df
TEST      DATE        PRODUCTS
A1        2014-02-28  T_01        7.9
                      T_1         8.1
                      T_2         8.6
          2014-03-03  T_01        7.4
                      T_1         8.4
                      T_2         8.7
...
```

And i want :

```
>>> df
TEST      DATE        PRODUCTS
A1        2014-02-28  T_01        7.9
                      T_1         8.1
                      T_2         8.7
                      T_3         9.6
          2014-03-03  T_01        7.4
                      T_1         8.4
                      T_2         8.7
                      T_3         9.7
...
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you saying that you want the sum of the values corresponding to your products for each date?

Comment: No I want add a PRODUCT which index is T_3 and equal to T_2 + 1. This for all TEST and DATE indexes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to add a T_3 row for each T_2 row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can `unstack` it first, generate the `T_3` and `stack` it back again.

```
In [15]:

print df
                            0
TEST DATE       PRODUCTS     
A1   2014-02-28 T_01      7.9
                T_1       8.1
                T_2       8.6
     2014-03-03 T_01      7.4
                T_1       8.4
                T_2       8.7

[6 rows x 1 columns]
In [16]:

df2 = df.unstack()[0] #if the variable name is 0
df2['T_3']=df2['T_2']+1
df2.stack() #need to convert to a DataFrame, 
Out[16]:
TEST  DATE        PRODUCTS
A1    2014-02-28  T_01        7.9
                  T_1         8.1
                  T_2         8.6
                  T_3         9.6
      2014-03-03  T_01        7.4
                  T_1         8.4
                  T_2         8.7
                  T_3         9.7
dtype: float64
```

## Edit

The Alternative is to manually add the `T_3` level:

```
In [37]:

df2=df.xs('T_2', level=2)+1
df2['PRODUCTS']='T_3'
df2.set_index('PRODUCTS', append=True, inplace=True)
df3=df.append(df2).sort_index()
In [38]:

print df3
                            0
TEST DATE       PRODUCTS     
A1   2014-02-28 T_01      7.9
                T_1       8.1
                T_2       8.6
                T_3       9.6
     2014-03-03 T_01      7.4
                T_1       8.4
                T_2       8.7
                T_3       9.7

[8 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you ! I need to pass by an unstack. Is that I fear for memory reason.

Comment: I feel that memory probably is not going to be an issue. You see, the number of total observations is unchanged (besides the newly generated `T_3`)

Comment: For my PC, even the number of observation is unchanged, I have a lot of memory trouble when I use stack/unstack and concat functions.

Comment: Ok, good to know that. See edit, which may be more memory friendly.